# Converting bytes to trites using IOTA libraries

Tags: legacy-protocol, ternary, java

Most IOTA libraries (at least C#, and Java) have a `Converter`, that has a [`getTrits`](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.csharp/wiki/M_Iota_Lib_CSharp_Api_Utils_Converter_GetTrits) method.

```
public static void GetTrits(
    sbyte[] bytes,
    int[] trits
)
```

It has two arrays as parameters. The input, `bytes`, and the output, `trits`. How can I compute the length of the necessary `trits` array for arbitrary length bytes?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [method you mentioned](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.csharp/blob/502d8bf520e91acb357d202def36407ebad01ae1/IotaCSharpApi/Api/Utils/Converter.cs#L115) converts each byte into 5 trits, so the output array needs to be 5 times the length of the input array.

Note that this function is not suitable for encoding **any** byte combinations, as bytes with value `243` to `255` will result in an error. It is only suitable for converting bytes back into trits, which have been converted from trits to bytes before.

For other ways of converting between trits and bytes, see [my answer to this question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/641/134).

Comment: I saw the other answer, but it was too complex :D I think I'd rather convert the bytes to hex strings, since converting strings to trytes is easier! Thank you!